# Keep getting a 404 with fetch on localhost/127.0.0.1

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, http-status-code-404

I am trying to communicate with my server that I run locally on vscode,
the client on a separate vscode window I have live server enabled(this should not matter I believe).

I keep getting 404 when I try to access the get all saves route.
Postman, shows the saves with the get route on localhost/saves but the server does not , and gives an 404.

I have looked around on stack and google, but did not found the solution or an idea to solve it.
Tried adding cors in the .use as well. but no changes.

Server side I have 2 files, 1 for the server itself, and the 1 that handles the routes.

server.js

```
dotenv = require('dotenv').config();


const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const serverRouter = require("./routers/serverRouter.js")
const dbRouter = require("./routers/dbRouter.js")
const cors = require("cors");
const port = 5500;
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const uri = process.env.MONGO_URI;

const allowedOrigins = ["http://127.0.0.1:5500", "http://localhost:5500"];


app.use(express.json());
app.use(serverRouter)
.use(dbRouter)
.use(
  cors({
      origin: function(origin, callback) {
          if (!origin) return callback(null, true);
          if (allowedOrigins.indexOf(origin) === -1) {
              var msg =
                  "The CORS policy for this site does not " +
                  "allow access from the specified Origin.";
              return callback(new Error(msg), false);
          }
          return callback(null, true);
      }
  })
);

mongoose.connect(uri) 
.then(() =>  {
  console.log("connected to mongoDb")
  app.listen(port, () => {
console.log(`server started on port ${port}`);
});
}).catch((error)=>{
  console.log(error);
});
```

dbRouter.js

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const cors = require("cors");
// const appRoot = require('app-root-path');
const ThemeSave = require('../../models/themeColor');
// const ThemeModel = require(`${appRoot}/models/themeColor`)

// const saves = [];

// const urlSite = "http:/127.0.0.1:5500"



router
  .post("/saves", async (req, res) => {
    try {

      const themeSave = await ThemeSave.create(req.body);
      res.status(200).json(themeSave);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }

    console.log(req.body);
    // res.send(req.body);

  })
  .get('/saves', async (req, res) => {
    console.log("trying");
    try {
      console.log("im here");
      const themeSave = await ThemeSave.find({});
      res.status(200).json(themeSave);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  })
  .get('/saves/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { id } = req.params;
      const themeSave = await ThemeSave.findById(id);
      res.status(200).json(themeSave);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  })
  .put('/saves/:id', async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { id } = req.params;
      const themeSave = await ThemeSave.findByIdAndUpdate(id, req.body);
      if(!themeSave){
        return res.status(404).json({message: `cannot find save with ID: ${id}`});
        console.log("hier");
      }
      // const updatedThemeSave = themeSave;
      res.status(200).json(themeSave);


    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  })
  .delete("/saves/:savename", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const {savename} = req.params;
           
      const saveNameToDelete = await ThemeSave.findOneAndDelete({"savename":{$regex: `${savename}`}});

      if(!saveNameToDelete){
        return res.status(404).json({message: `cannot find savename with name: ${saveNameToDelete}`});
      }
      res.status(200).json(saveNameToDelete);

    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  })
  .get("/getsave/:savename", async (req, res) => {
    try {
      const { savename } = req.params;
      console.log(savename);
      const themeSave = await ThemeSave.findOne(JSON.parse(savename));
      console.log(themeSave);
      res.status(200).json(themeSave);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error.message);
      res.status(500).json({ message: error.message });
    }
  }).patch("/saves/:savename", async(req,res)=>{
    //update part of the savename object?
    
  });


module.exports = router;
```

here is my try on the client side

```
function getSaveObject(){
  const url = "/saves";






  fetch(url)
  .then(response => {
    // {
      //handle response            
      // console.log(`responce:  ${response.json()}`);
      return response.text();// <-- gives the error msg in html(tho saves is json)
   })
  .then(data => {
    //handle data
    console.log(`data:  ${data}`);
    return data;
  }).then(responseData => {console.log("responseData"),console.log(responseData);})
  .catch(error => {
    //handle error

    console.log("im here error!");
      throw new Error(`HTTP error: ${error}`);
  });
};
```

responce shows in 127.0.0.1:5500/saves

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Error</title>
</head>
<body>
<pre>Cannot GET /saves</pre>
</body>
</html>
```

and the json that comes from localhost:5500/saves is

```
[
    {
        "_id": "64e93d25ada563cc8dff0ff0",
        "savename": "Save 2",
        "textsize": 16,
        "__v": 0
    },
    {
        "_id": "64e93e6717c146671f1083bf",
        "savename": "Save 6",
        "textsize": 2,
        "createdAt": "2023-08-25T23:51:03.598Z",
        "updatedAt": "2023-08-26T01:07:12.166Z",
        "__v": 0
    }]
```

so what am I missing and how can I make it work.

Comment: Isn't this a "port" issue, have you tried to go to "http://127.0.0.1:5500/saves" on client ?

Comment: script.js:209     GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/saves 404 (Not Found) thats the line i get on inspect on the site, and line 209 is:  fetch(url)

Comment: it cant be triggering of live server or maybe using same port?

Answer (score 0):

you didn't add the port from your url. You should call it localhost:5500/saves or 127.0.0.1:5500/saves both will work. But if you only call it 127.0.0.1/saves. Then surely that is a 404.

Comment: in console it shows it uses the 5500 automatically, as it says: script.js:209     GET http://127.0.0.1:5500/saves 404 (Not Found)

Comment: try to changes your variable "url" to "http://localhost:5500/saves"
const url = "http://localhost:5500/saves" from getSaveObject function.

Comment: i did: Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:5500/saves' from origin 'http://127.0.0.1:5500' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.
script.js:209     GET http://localhost:5500/saves net::ERR_FAILED 200 (OK)
getSaveObject @ script.js:209
(anonymous) @ script.js:111
script.js:224 im here error!
script.js:225 Uncaught (in promise) Error: HTTP error: TypeError: Failed to fetch
    at script.js:225:13

Comment: did you add http:// to the url? YOur server and client both running on port 5500?

Comment: without http i get script.js:209 Fetch API cannot load localhost:5500/saves. URL scheme "localhost" is not supported.,   with http i get the has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.

Comment: and server runs on 5500, on my pc, and on same pc i go to the site http://localhost:5500/saves or http://127.0.0.1:5500

Comment: i dont get the cors error when i do 127.0.0.1:5500/saves but still getting the 404

Answer (score 0):

I have it working now,

I added

```
res.header("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "http://127.0.0.1:5500");
```

on the route

I used http://lcoalhost:5500/saves as URL in the fetch.

and that seemed to solved the 404 error